# php encoding when variable declared

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, arabic

Hi I've been working on project that work fine on my localserver wampserver, but when I used 000webhost server my pages where the variable was declared like this

`$var="جدول أعمال الجماعة";`

it was converted like this

`$var="Ù‚Ø³Ù… Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙˆØ§Ø±Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø´Ø±ÙŠØ©";`

I have tried evrything like encoding my file with UTF-8 with and without BOM and tried to replaced still the same problem I have read every article about encoding and tried evrything like

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
```

nothing worked for me so far.

Comment: Check your FTP transfer settings, it might be set to ASCII, try transfering as binary.

Comment: nop didnt work on my notepad++ its declared correct but on server side it just §Ù„Ø¨Ø´Ø±ÙŠØ©  even if i download the file from my server its open fine